# Calling c++ functions from javascript using require

Tags: c++, node.js, swig, node-gyp

I hava a c++ code which when executed will be creating a console app that will show the scanned document/barcode from the device via USB.  I found ways to communicate with c++ from javascript using [swig](http://swig.org/) wrapper generator and node-gyp.  Now I'm able to access the c++ methods from js using require function.  How can I make javascript to work the similar way as the actual (creating console app)c++ program.  Anybody suggest any ways to do that.

Comment: To the I extend I understand your problem the best solution is to create a web APIs methods and access the URL through Ajax. Ajax is the traditional way to make an asynchronous HTTP request. Data can be sent using the HTTP POST method and received using the HTTP GET method.

Comment: Describe *work the similar way as the actual c++*.